# Start another EXE with command line parameters in C#

Tags: c#, command-line-interface, exe

I want do start an EXE file with Parameters.

I tried with Button1 to start a consoleapp (works). With Button2 i tried to open the same consoleapp with Parameters (works). With Button3 i tried to open the WindowsFromsApplication with Parameters. The WindowsFromsApplication does not run and casts a WindowsMessage, that it can't be opend (but not in the debugmode).

If I use same WindowsFromsApplication wit a desktop shortcut and parameters it works.

What is wrong my solution?

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\\ParamTest1.exe");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\\ParamTest1.exe", "Test");
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\\Tool.exe","UserName Password");
    }
```

The Code of tool.exe:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new FormMain(args));
    }
}
```

And the FormMain:

```
public partial class FormMain: Form
{
    string Raptoruser = "";

    public FormMain(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
```

...

Visual Studio copies the EXE as planned in the debug Folder.

Comment: Please read [ask]. "It does not work" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: What does "does not work" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code for "tool.exe"?

Comment: Please show the exact command line you use in the shortcut.

Comment: I notice you are running a different executable in your third line. In your question you seem to imply that it works in debug mode but not release mode ("it can't be opend (but not in the debugmode)"). Might be something as simple as `Tool.exe` not existing in your release folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an arguments using ProcessStartInfo.Arguments property. And notice, that if your args contains the spaces you need to add quotes around your args, so, I suggest you need to correct your code smth like this:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(Application.StartupPath + "\\Tool.exe")
{
    Arguments = String.Format(@"""{0} {1}""", UserName, Password)
}
);
```

AND also make sure your Tool.exe is placed in the same location with the executable file of the solution.

Comment: "Try this" doesn't explain why or how you think this will solve the problem (not my downvote)

Comment: Try using proper spelling and explaining what you changed. What you changed is adding quotes, which could also just be expressed as `Process.Start("Tool.exe", @"""Username Password""")`, but if that works it would make OP's claim _"with a shortcut and parameters it works"_ incorrect.

Comment: And now your answer is just incorrect. You don't _need_ to use `ProcessStartInfo` and its `Arguments` property, that's what the `Process.Start(string, string)` overload is for. Also, you don't need quotes around arguments if those arguments are _meant to be separated_ by spaces.

Comment: I just suggest an example of the stronger code for different types of arguments - if you try to send a path as an argument (ex: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\....) you need to add quotes around it, so I just want to share more universal solution for the problem. Sorry, if I can't help.

Comment: With this solution the tool accepts only one Parameter, but i think i can deal with it.